# Typescript Interfaces - Implement function with narrowed union type parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a generic React component which allows number, string, or Date values.  I want users of the component to be able to define a callback when the value is updated, and to allow for that callback to define the value as *either* a number, string, or Date.

Here's a watered-down example of what I'm trying to do overall (I'm aware that this specific example could be fixed by forcing `value` to always be a `string` but that's not the purpose of this question):

```
import React from 'react';

// Union Type
type ValueType = number | string | Date;

// Generic Component
interface InputProps {
  value: ValueType;
  onChange: (value: ValueType) => void;  // <-- need to change this signature to.. something
}
const Input = ({ value, onChange }: InputProps) => (
  <input value={value.toString()} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
);

// Implementation of Generic Component
interface TestProps {
  onInputUpdate: (value: string) => void;
}
const Test = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
  <Input 
    value="test" 
    onChange={(e: string) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // <-- 'number' is not assignable to 'string'
  />
);

export default Test;
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to make it work the way I want it to.

I've also tried using generics i.e. `onChange: <T extends ValueType>(value: T) => void` with similar results.

There are two ways I know I can "fix" it, but I'd like to avoid them if possible:

- Making the signature `onChange: (value: any) => void`
- Forcing users to use the `ValueType` type when implementing their callback

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**:  `onChange: (value: any) => void` can allow the function to be implemented as `onChange: (value: string) => {}`, is there a way to do this but restrict it to being types which are part of `ValueType` instead of `any`?

Comment: How do you go about getting a `T` from `e.target.value` (which is always a `string` in your example)?  You can fix it with `interface InputProps<T extends ValueTypes>` and using `T` in the field definitions, but then you run into the problem that `Input` _must_ be of `InputProps<string>` as you've written in now.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm30jW) work for you?  You want `value` to always be exactly one of `string`, `number`, or `Date`?  Never more specifc (literal types like `"a"`) or more wide (unions like `string | number`)?

Comment: In my actual code, `value` is coming from a callback in a child component's prop via useContext, which can be `number | string | Date`.

Comment: @jcalz, it would technically be possible for `value` to be more specific or wider than any single type, as long as the type of `value` is contained within `ValueType`.  But what you provided is definitely a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach here instead of generics is to represent `InputProps` as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of three different object types; one member for `string` values, one for `number` values, and one for `Date` values:

```
type InputProps = {
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
} | {
    value: number;
    onChange: (value: number) => void;
} | {
    value: Date;
    onChange: (value: Date) => void;
}
```

You can generate this union programmatically from `ValueType` by [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) your original definition across the `ValueType` union:

```
type InputProps = ValueType extends infer T ?
    T extends unknown ? { value: T, onChange: (value: T) => void } : never : never;
```

Now you will be able to use `Input` the way you expected to:

```
const Test = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
    <Input
        value="test"
        onChange={(e: string) => onInputUpdate(e)}
    />
);
```

with a caveat here that the compiler apparently wants to see the parameter to `onChange` annotated (`e` above); if you leave it off it fails to infer the type and falls back to `any`.

Also, the compiler is unlikely to be able to verify safety of the *implementation* of `Input`.  This is because the correlation between `value` and `onChange` will be lost when you destructure it, so I'd use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) there:

```
const Input = ({ value, onChange }: InputProps) => (
    <input
        value={value.toString()}
        onChange={(e) => (onChange as (value: ValueType) => void)(e.target.value)}
    />
);
```

This may not be the best thing for your use case, but I wanted folks who come here to be aware of this possibility too.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgFUA7YCBuAFQE8wlyYuk4ANRQAbAK5JO3OAF44DMSABGSKHAA+cAM4wowBgHMNcACIoYSCtQBUNOAHEkDVcDRwAwrkjOGMcvosoTHQBAEkGMDEYAAUcMC04AG9yOFS4ADdRCQAuISzJfgo0uBZ3AAsUQyRcgApM8Wq8hqkkAEpZAD4MiGAAE1JUuwAeAFoR+SQkXrgYCDg0CqqZsuAErWADBnMxIhmIADp97VwkGBXDcgBfW0o+aXDImLiEuWFm-jgkAA8LBl6E-SYVTsOAAfhSaTYnx+Tn+cDEDAA1gwIAB3VigpIZfK5NgAGhKDHKlQMjTqOPY7RkXXSPWmlzguWc6WBTKQLKgVio1hmHweUViEHisiSENS9Ry2l0+gMRTSpUWpNqEsaOj0hipNLpFAZmmSxRVTMUKk5YsJxKqyopCmUqk13T6OuM+rShtM5ksZoVJLJbrMFnttMdVzgN3IaBYOjg-PgchqiWxDQJ3qWl1yMcF8XtNTNQ30jzNBvyMkSKv2swAytLDDVWpdC-KiYqkCWam1OnAainSXAUAlyQ1cm8JC1A3TWgOJHWzVQOuRWlzaKFwCIkCAnDBzMxWBBMA4nC43J5wCwN-5fKpgmgBGwkDpMwkXakWDG6GBeh6rYOpeqDGPg-WEYMFGt5RnGCYvhEURvh+FhwGm7B3k8QpaNmuYxg24rFgARBYOjYZh5rNq2qrVn+HaQY8MEem207FLO85WN8kCwHAvRIMEYgiPAoEwFYQA)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for smth like that:

```js
import React from 'react';

// Union Type
type ValueType = number | string | Date;

// Generic Component
interface InputProps<T extends ValueType> {
  value: T;
  onChange: <U=T>(value: U) => void;  // <-- need to change this signature to.. something
}
const Input = <T extends ValueType>({ value, onChange }: InputProps<T>) => (
  <input value={value.toString()} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
);

// Implementation of Generic Component
interface TestProps<T extends ValueType> {
  onInputUpdate: <U = T>(value: U) => void;
}
const Test = <T extends ValueType>({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps<T>) => (
  <Input<number>
    value={2}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is number
  />
);

const Test2 = <T extends ValueType>({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps<T>) => (
  <Input<string>
    value="Hello"
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is string
  />
);

const Test3 = <T extends ValueType>({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps<T>) => (
  <Input<Date>
    value={new Date()}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is Date
  />
);

export default Test;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgFUA7YCBuAFQE8wlyYuk4ANRQAbAK5JO3OAF44DMSABGSKHAA%20cAM4wowBgHMNcACIoYSCtVoBxJA1XA0cAMK5IDhjHL6LUTOgCAJIMYGIwAAo4YFoAPGxwSAAeFgwAJlpCohJSSAB8cADe5HBwAG7ZSABc7BSlLC4AFiiG1XCxdDJseQAUFeJtdACUsgVlEMBppKU0cOQAvuRoLDpwIWHwcvGJKfYZWQO5vYXllQA0cA3NrXDzNevhURAx8XkjMgU9Je36G6cDMkK-QkADoYBAAMq6fQGHpDeaXBhNFoGJCAnpId4FK4opAYsEoKComAg4GYhFUPLkIZWWZBcAiJAgewwczMVgQTBwOwOPTONzgFgsnxeVQBNACNhIHRPF4JZKpfbCQ78ArFeoMB4wOhgNLmNodWTsXpkmrDUblCZTBZLFbwKWrLby3bpTLKnKqnonFhanV6iy3GoOyLROLdLFwL6lWJa2IKZSqKmlUpkwEAJkWycRyNa6MxFp9oXCfv1GPhM1oEAA1hcBMBMvGVFBvpTqVZlgxVsG00btgq9m7KkcvYjfbr9YH2NKQ88w28LVH2rGdHpDEnk6mAEQACSQIhEEE33w1OdReYjhY2JYsZYRcFm1drcHr2mhhhbVJplA7XenAGZe2dRVBxVbhjlHIttXHAM7inGVQ1eCNFxjSDYjMCx1xTSpAQcAB3UxS3hY9s2uM9CjLAtNUg688XJCtLhrRJn0ydCeBmT8rGSSBYDgNIkACMQRHtacKCAA)

There is one drawback: if you provide generic parameter for `onInputUpdate` it can broke the types.
For example:

```js
const Test3 = <T extends ValueType>({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps<T>) => (
  <Input<Date>
    value={new Date()}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate<string>(e)}  // e is string instead of expected Date
  />
);
```

**SECOND APPROACH**

```js
import React from 'react';

// Union Type
type ValueType = number | string | Date;

// Generic Component
interface InputProps<T extends ValueType> {
  value: T;
  onChange: <U=T>(value: U) => void;  // 
}
const Input = <T extends ValueType>({ value, onChange }: InputProps<T>) => (
  <input value={value.toString()} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
);

// Implementation of Generic Component
interface TestProps {
  onInputUpdate: <U>(value: U) => void;
}

const Test = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
  <Input
    value={2}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is literal 2
  />
);

const Test2 = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
  <Input
    value={'2'}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is literal "2"
  />
);

const Test3 = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
  <Input
    value={new Date()}
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is Date
  />
);


const Test4 = ({ onInputUpdate }: TestProps) => (
  <Input
    value={['1']} // error, it hsould be ValueType
    onChange={(e) => onInputUpdate(e)}  // ok, e is Date
  />
);
export default Test;
```

Comment: I tried going down this route too; it may end up being what I do in the end, but all of the generics make things a little messy, especially when the `Test` component is dealing with more than just one `Input` component.

Comment: @twhitcomb could you please provice an example where exactly you have an issue with my code? I will try to handle it

Comment: I'd prefer for users (i.e. those who'd be implementing the `Test` components in this example) to not have to refer to `ValueType` directly; I'd rather TypeScript be able to determine if the type the user used for `value` as an argument to `onChange` is part of `ValueType` by defining it in the `InputProps` interface.  It's very possible that what I'm asking isn't possible in TypeScript though, in which case I'll probably implement something similar to what you've suggested.

Comment: @twhitcomb I made an update, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Define the interface like this:

```
interface InputProps<T extends ValueType> {
    value:T,
    onChange: ((value: T) => void);
}
```

Although I may have misunderstood you - if value can vary over any of those types at run-time, you would instead have to do a type test in the handler I think.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this has to do with [strictFunctionTypes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654):

```
interface InputProps {
  value: ValueType;
  onChange(value: ValueType): void;  // onChange declared as a method (does what I expect)

  // onChange: (value: ValueType) => void;  // onChange declared as a property (strict)
}
```

Comment: Oh, uh, you *could* do this, but then nothing will complain if you write `value="test" onChange={(e: number) => e.toFixed(2)}`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: That's definitely a good point; and the only way around that would be to use generics.  But I think that's a separate issue I have to figure out.